# Get value and set in bottom navigation in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to get a cart value and add as a badge in Flutter bottom navigation but value is not getting set after the function

My code

```
void _getCartValue() {
      getCartcount().then((value) => {print(value), cartlength = value});
      // setState(() {});
    }

    _getCartValue();
```

Bottom navigation code

```
 BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: 'Cart',
        icon: Badge(
          shape: BadgeShape.circle,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
          child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
          badgeContent: Container(
            height: 15,
            width: 15,
            decoration:
                BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
            child: Text(
              cartlength.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 10,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

The value is printing inside the function but I'm unable to get the value below the function. Help me to pass the value from  `_getCartValue` to `cartlength` value

I'm getting null below the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change external variable value inside the async execution body `..then, ..whenComple, ..catchError`
Maybe you can try this

```
void _getCartValue() async {
  try {
    final value = await getCartCount();
    cartlength = value;
    // setState(() {});
  } catch (_) {}
}

_getCartValue();
```

**Edit**
A clean approach is to wrap your `Text` widget with `FutureBuilder` like this

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: getCartCount,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return ConnectionState.done == snapshot.connectionState ? Text(
      snapshot.data.toString(),
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 10,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ) : SizedBox(width: 10.0, height: 10.0, child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  },
),
```

Comment: when i print the value its coming as Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'

Comment: Boss to print your value prefix it with `await`. Ex : `print(await _getCartValue());`

Comment: that is fine how to pass that value in bottom navigation

Comment: final value = await getCartcount(); i am trying like this but value is null

Comment: I mistakenly omitted `await` on `getCartCount`. Retry with this

Comment: still null only

Comment: thanks working fine but its reloading all the time

Comment: Where you are updating cart count ? Post additional code if you think it can be necessary

Comment: should i have to add in init state to stop reload?

Comment: What you mean by "reload" ?

Comment: its reloading every 5 secs

Comment: Using a `Timer` ? What stop mechanism you want to use ? After a specific number of reload times or after obtaining some value ?